# Amount of space between text and a line containing a \rule

Tags: spacing, rules

If a `\rule` is placed below a line of text, some space is inserted between the line and the rule. Usually, the amount of space appears to precisely add the difference to the height of the current font size, regardless of whether text is actually inserted (cf. figure, right column, row 1/2) or not (left column). However, if the rule's height surpasses the font height, there is some additional space between the lines (row 3).

Of what amount is this space?

[image]

(The purpose of the last row is to quickly demonstrate that the identical results in spacing in the two columns in rows 1-3 are independently achieved.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xparse}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3.5}

\newlength{\mydepth}
\newlength{\myheight}
\newlength{\mywidth}
\newlength{\colwidth}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\sbox{\mybox}{\Huge ipsum}
\settodepth{\mydepth}{\Huge ipsum}
\settowidth{\mywidth}{\Huge ipsum}

\setlength{\colwidth}{\mywidth+2em}


%typeset \mybox underlined with a rule of mandatory height #3,
%and place an optional text #2 either right or left of the rule,
%as indicated by a star (#1).
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\placebox}{s o m}{
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\mywidth+2em}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \rule[-\mydepth]{2em}{\mydepth}%
        \usebox{\mybox}\\%
        \IfValueTF{#2}{#2}{}%
        \rule{\mywidth+1em}{#3}%
    }{%else invert left/right placement
        \usebox{\mybox}%
        \rule[-\mydepth]{2em}{\mydepth}\\%
        \rule{\mywidth+1em}{#3}%
        \IfValueTF{#2}{#2}{}%
    }%fi
    \end{minipage}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{b{\colwidth}b{\colwidth}}
\placebox{1mm} & \placebox*[\Huge A]{1mm}\\[2em]
\placebox{1mm} & \placebox*[A]{1mm}\\
\placebox{2mm} & \placebox*[A]{2mm}\\
\placebox{4mm} & \placebox*[A]{4mm}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you mean `nointerlineskip`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Almost -- I was looking for the _amount_ of space. But `\lineskip` was indeed what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To understand the behaviour it is instructive to go to the TeX primitive rules. These are defined using three dimensions height, width and depth:

```
\vrule height1pt width 1pt depth0pt fjord\par
\hrule height1pt width 100pt depth0pt fjord
```

LaTeX defines the `\rule` using these primitives disguised as follows:

```
\def\rule{\@ifnextchar[\@rule{\@rule[\z@]}} width height raised
\def\@rule[#1]#2#3{%
 \leavevmode
 \hbox{%
 \setlength\@tempdima{#1}%
 \setlength\@tempdimb{#2}%
 \setlength\@tempdimc{#3}%
 \advance\@tempdimc\@tempdima
 \vrule\@width\@tempdimb\@height\@tempdimc\@depth-\@tempdima}}
```

If we construct an example using first the TeX primitives,

```
 \vrule height1pt width 1pt depth0pt fjord
 \hrule height1pt width 100pt depth0pt fjord
```

we get

[image]

We get a different behaviour with LaTeX rules as they are typeset in horizontal mode and TeX adds a normal parskip as required..

```
\rule{1pt}{1pt}fjord fjord fjord fjord\par
\rule{30pt}{1pt}fjord fjord fjord fjord
```

[image]

Full minimal

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent0pt
\parskip0pt
\begin{document}
\vrule height0.4pt width 1pt depth0pt fjord\par
\hrule height0.4pt width 30pt depth0pt fjord

\rule{1pt}{1pt}fjord fjord fjord fjord\par
\rule{30pt}{1pt}fjord fjord fjord fjord
\end{document}
```

The amount of space left is normally lineskip for LaTeX plus `\parskip` in the examples. vary the parskip value to see how the lines get moved. Note that both start the rule at the baseline of the letters.

Comment: `\lineskip` is what I was looking for -- thanks. Had you not mentioned `\parskip`, I might have also missed its rubber length. Strangely though, increasing `\lineskip` immediatley after `begin{minipage}` in my code seems to only _affect_ the third row (while it is always correctly changed, as checked with `\the`). Do you have any idea why this could be the case?

Comment: This question is of course directly related to the fact that even though `\the\lineskip` prints `1pt` (without rubber lengths), no such space is inserted in rows 1 and 2 of the figure given in the OP. Since all boxes are printed by the same command, this is somewhat surprising.

Comment: `\lineskip` is inserted between two lines only when b-(h+d) < s, where b is the baselineskip, h is the height of the line below, d is the depth of the line above and s is a dimen parameter called `\lineskiplimit`. Otherwise the skip inserted is just b-(h+d) in order to keep the two baselines b apart.

Comment: The default value of `\lineskiplimit` is 0pt. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51395/4427

Comment: @egreg I see. Assuming s >= 0, that translates to "if the baselines are separated by more than b-s anyway, make them even further apart", which at first sight seems peculiar. What's the reason for that?

Comment: @dgs You're looking from a wrong point of view. If the two lines are "too near" (and this "too near" is measured by `\lineskiplimit`), then they are separated  *exactly* by `\lineskip`. So if d=3pt, h=10pt and b=12pt, then the distance between the two baselines will be (3+10+1)pt (assuming `\lineskip=1pt` and `\lineskiplimit=0pt`) and the same if s > 0. If s=2pt, d=3pt, h=7.5pt, b=12pt, then the distance between the baselines will be (3+7.5+1)pt (less than the normal baselineskip). Setting `\lineskiplimit` to positive values is usually done only in special cases.